# Google Analytics Goals Regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Destination (Regex): //thank-you//i

Funnel Step 1: /^((?!/thank-you/).)*/

Doesn't work. I want a funnel where step one is any uri except for the goal destination /thank-you/

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: This might work: ^(?!(\/thank\-you\/)$)

Comment: Google Analytics wont allow lookbacks or lookaheads

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your use case. If somebody calls the goal destination the goal is completed, so it is not possible to have the destination as a goal step in the first place.

So there would be no point in excluding the destination url from the funnel (which, as pointed out in the comment, is not possible in any case).

And frankly, funnel Visualisation sucks - skipped steps get backfilled, repeated steps are only counted once, funnel steps have no effect on goal completion (which continuously seems to baffle people), it's impossible to evaluate the order in which funnel steps where taken etc. (more on that in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313?hl=en)).

So while the immediate answer to your question is "it does not work that way in GA" the more helpful answer is probably "do not use funnels, use the behavior flow / goal flow views" (which actually allows you to trace the users path through your site).

Comment: If you don't use the funnel anyone landing on the destination page will trigger a goal.

Using the funnel and including a required step ensures this doesnt happen.

Not excluding the destination page as a step will trigger a goal if the user lands on the destination page as it just counts it for both.